# Errors in the ScriptResource.axd always end with the same query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I get a few errors in my logs every day with the ScriptResource.axd

```
at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.Throw404()
at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I have done quite a bit of research and managed to reduce the of times this error is occuring. However I have noticed that the query string always ends the same, from the &"t=" onwards.

```
ScriptResource.axd?d=Q...1&t=eeeeeeeeb4904b79
```

(URL shortened for readability, and it's not indexed by search engines)

Is this significant, just a coincidence or is it meant to be that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal to see the same "t" variable on the querystring. ASP.NET uses that parameter "cache bust" and ensure that a fresh version is forced down to the client after each build.